# Setting up Forever to listen for events

Tags: node.js, forever

I am writing a new nodejs server and I would like to use forever to keep it running.  So far its been pretty easy:

```
forever start simple-server.js
```

However is there a way that I can catch specific events (like an error event) such that the server does not shutdown and restart on an uncaught error.  IE I would like to just log the error and continue. At this point I see a message like this stating that my server has been restarted each time an error is thrown:

```
Forever detected script exited with code: 1
Forever restarting script for 2 time
```

I know that I can programatically use forever but I have a couple problems:
1. Seems like when I use it programatically the process is not listed in 'forever list'
2. If I setup a handler for an 'error' event does forever still restart the server?

```
var forever = require('forever');

var server = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
  max: 3,
  silent: true,
  options: []
});

server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Just received an error in server: ' + err);
});

server.on('exit', function() {
  console.log('server exiting');
});

server.start();
```

Comment: Well, yes...you `catch` the errors within `simple-server.js`.

Comment: So you want me to wrap all code in try/catch?  I call other apis that may throw errors as well.  In the end I am used to app servers that are threaded and just the worker thread process a request dies not the entire server.

Comment: Well, that's the major difference: Node runs on a single thread. The only way to prevent the server from restarting is to catch as many errors as you can.

Comment: Sure and that is why I am using forever. Would be nice to be able to catch errors at a high level, like in forever and handle them.  In my case I would be fine with a log entry.